# Concatenate multiple rows into one field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with three column like image (Source) and want to write a query that give a table like image (Result)

[image]

Comment: column of 103 clear from image but exist!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer,
    stuff((
            SELECT ',' + cast(policy as varchar(10))
            FROM table1 b
            WHERE a.customerid = b.customerid
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') [policies]
FROM table1 a
```

Comment: Error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: @SajjadZare CAST/CONVERT policy to a VARCHAR to prevent the error

Comment: but the type of column 'policy' in  source table is int

Comment: That's why you need to handles policy as a varchar, since comma's are not valid within integers.