# Convert table to text in result of a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Result of a query is table,is it possible to write a query that convert this result to a text (for example imagine that result is a table with 4 rows with value 1 to 4 and convert it to 1,2,3,4)

Comment: instead why don't you your original table structure,relation,requirement and few sample data.
you ask same question here ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699636/write-query-that-give-result-like-image/20699732#20699732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `FOR XML PATH('')`. For example:

```
create table test(col varchar(10))

insert into test values ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')

select STUFF( (select ',' + col 
                from test 
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query

```
declare @Var varchar(1000);
set @var = ''
select @Var = @var + CONVERT(varchar, Column1) + ','
from Table1

select @var
```

Comment: works, but limited to length of datatype of @Var. 

`FOR XML`

 has size limit of 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @result varchar(1000)

SET @result = ''

SELECT @result = @result + StudentId + ',' FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz

select substring(@result, 1, len(@result) -1  --trim extra "," at end
```

Op like

1,2,3,4,..........

Happy Coding