# Querying from awkward, repetative tables - use 'for each' loop or pivot or cursor?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, cursor, pivot

I have two tables with a large amount of columns which I need to get into a useable table for front end programming

The first table has the definitions and the second has the data. The first part of each table has some additional data that is used when matchine for the join:

#### Table 1 columns:

```
    Machine
    plan_number
    plan_name
    plan_version
    Name_A_001
    Name_B_001
    Name_A_002
    Name_B_002
    .
    .
    .
    Name_A_400
    Name_B_400
```

#### Table 2 columns:

```
    Date
    Machine
    plan_number
    plan_version
    count_001
    check_001
    count_002
    check_002
    .
    .
    .
    count_400
    check_400
```

And I would like to be able to select a date range and output to a table of the following format for each of the columns 'xxx':

#### Desired Output:

```
    Date
    Machine
    plan_number
    plan_version
    plan_name
    Name_A_xxx + Name_B_xxx
    Count_xxx
```

I can do this using a simple join statement for each column but this is difficult to manage over 400 columns (this may increase). My instinct would be to do a loop similar to the following:

```
    for each value in ('001', '002', '003'.................'400')
    -->loop code for single column concatenating the value each time
```

Now I know this is neither efficient or wise so I am looking for the best possible way to deal with such large numbers of columns

Edit: some sample data as requested below:

#### Table 1:

```
MACHINE PLAN_NUMBER PLAN_VERSION PLAN_NAME     Name_A_001     Name_B_001     Name_A_002     Name_B_002     Name_A_003     Name_B_003     Name_A_004     Name_B_004      Name_A_005      Name_B_005
3989    1           5            COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124  Top            PTL_INW_N_423                 CRK_INW_U_325                 CRK_INW_S_323                  PTL_INW_L_421
3994    1           5            COMBINED_102  DUB_INW_D      Top            PTL_INW_N                     CRK_INW_U                     CRK_INW_S                      PTL_INW_L
```

#### Table 2:

```
Date        MACHINE PLAN_NUMBER PLAN_VERSION COUNT_001 CHECK_001 COUNT_002 CHECK_002 COUNT_003 CHECK_003 COUNT_004 CHECK_004 COUNT_005 CHECK_005
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            4         0         39        0         11        0         2         0         1         0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            2         0         51        0         16        0         1         0         6         0
11/02/2014  3994    2           15           44        1         317       0         275       1         124       0         106       0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            11        0         112       0         61        0         15        0         7         0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            64        0         543       0         0         0         114       0         4         0
11/02/2014  3994    2           15           61        0         734       1         0         0         101       0         4         0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            166       0         1344      0         0         0         215       0         32        1
11/02/2014  3994    2           15           13        0         87        0         0         0         35        0         1         0
11/02/2014  3989    1           5            3         0         9         0         0         0         1         0         0         0
```

#### Desired output

```
Date        MACHINE  PLAN_NUMBER  PLAN_VERSION  PLAN_NAME     Name_A_xxx + Name_B_xxx  Count_xxx
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        4
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        2
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  DUB_INW_D Top            44
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        11
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        64
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  DUB_INW_D Top            61
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        166
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  DUB_INW_D Top            13
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  DUB_INW_D_124 Top        3
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            39
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            51
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_N                317
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            112
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            543
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_N                734
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            1344
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_N                87
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_N_423            9
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            11
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            16
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_U                275
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            61
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            0
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_U                0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            0
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_U                0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_U_325            0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            2
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            1
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_S                124
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            15
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            114
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_S                101
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            215
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  CRK_INW_S                35
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  CRK_INW_S_323            1
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            1
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            6
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_L                106
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            7
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            4
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_L                4
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            0
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            32
11/02/2014  3994     2            15            COMBINED_102  PTL_INW_L                1
11/02/2014  3989     1            5             COMBINED_101  PTL_INW_L_421            0
```

Comment: are you looking something like this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699636/write-query-that-give-result-like-image/20699732#20699732

Comment: Not really, I think that example was putting similar rows together, combining one column, I have a huge amount of columns and dont need the data on the same row in the new table, thanks though

Comment: Frankly explain lil more.output is not clear.what is columns 'xxx' ?how Name_A_xxx + Name_B_xxx ?

Comment: Replace xxx with the values in ('001', '002', '003'.................'400') for example so Name_A_001 + Name_B_001 then next loop will be Name_A_002 + Name_B_002

Comment: In example make your both table short say only 10 column.populate with sample data.now what parameter you will pass and how the output should look like.use sq l-fiddle man.definitely the link i have given will be used.Is there anything else which tell that column name end with "001" or "002" .

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely you can use a view to join that 2 tables.
If you got trouble writing a 400 columns query for that query you can at least do some query to write that to you.

I suggest you can do something like:

```
Select sc0.name
 from sys.sysobjects so0
 join sys.syscolumns sc0 on sc0.id =  so0.id
 join sys.syscolumns sc1 on sc1.name = so0.name
 join sys.sysobjects so1 on sc1.id =  so1.id
 where so0.xtype = N'U' and so1.xtype = N'U'
 and so0.name = N'Table 1'
 and so1.name = N'Table 2'
```

the query above ill return all matching columns from both tables.
Use it to automatize that view creation and use the view.

Comment: Thanks, I have the join working fine, it's the automation of this which is my problem, logically I would have used a where loop to go through each column but I understand this is wrong and inefficient for SQL