# How to output a single column or concatenate another one if multiple rows are in group in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

Imagine the following structure:

```
Group   Color    ColorDesc
-----   -----    -----
1       'Red'    'The cool name of Red Color'
1       'Green'  'The cool name of Green Color'
2       'Blue'   'The cool name of Blue Color'
2       'Yellow' 'The cool name of Yellow Color'
2       'Purple' 'The cool name of Purple Color'
3       'Pink'   'The cool name of Pink Color'
```

I would like to group the rows on `Group` field, аnd if there is only one row in a group, I need to output the colorDesc column (as for `Group`=3 below), but if there are more than one column, I would like to get a delimited string on field color (as for 1 and 2). Desired output:

```
Group   GroupedColor
-----   -----
1       'Red', 'Green'
2       'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple'
3       'The cool name of Pink Color'
```

I can create a multi-parameter CLR aggregate and live happily, but is there an efficient way to achieve this with native T-SQL?

Comment: refer this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699636/write-query-that-give-result-like-image/20699732#20699732

Comment: you are looking for xmlpath with stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @t table(Groups int,Color varchar(50),ColorDesc varchar(50))
insert into @t
select 1 ,'Red',    'The cool name of Red Color' union all
select 1,'Green',  'The cool name of Green Color'  union all
select 2,'Blue',   'The cool name of Blue Color'  union all
select 2,'Yellow', 'The cool name of Yellow Color'  union all
select 2,'Purple', 'The cool name of Purple Color'  union all
select 3,'Pink',   'The cool name of Pink Color'

;with cte as
(
select groups,count(*) cnt from @t group by groups
)

select  distinct b.groups,case when cnt=1 then a.ColorDesc
else stuff((select ',' + color from @t c where c.groups=b.Groups for xml path('') ),1,1,'') end
from  cte b inner join @t a on a.Groups=b.Groups

Without distinct(Test both with lot of data)

Select * from 
(select  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.groups order by b.groups) rn, b.groups,case when cnt=1 then a.ColorDesc
else stuff((select ',' + color from @t c where c.groups=b.Groups for xml path('') ),1,1,'') end colorDesc
from  cte b inner join @t a on a.Groups=b.Groups )t4 where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works. Next thing I try to do, is avoid the 'distinct' keyword, since the code technically first concatenates strings for all items, and then scans these to remove duplicates. I tend to output whatever required, without adding overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Whichever way you go to avoid distinct,those sql will be long and use some-other technique like row__number etc .I think this is most short and hence efficient.Also i am not aware of real data and table.If there are lot of data then you have to use paging no matter what.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just thinking about row_number at the moment. But I also think that short query (in terms of symbol length) does not always mean efficient. It's pretty hard to visualize the data structure here, I tried to show the easiest moments. But thanks for the hints!

Comment: I think that query optimization is beyond the subject of the initial question, so I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Group,
    STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + Color
            FROM Table1 S
            WHERE T.Group = S.Group 
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') [GroupedColor]
FROM Table1 T
```

Comment: In this case I don't get the 2nd column for Group=3 displayed with long name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Group, 
       SUBSTRING((Select ','+
                      CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Group) FROM T1 WHERE T2.Group=T1.Group)=1 
                      THEN T1.ColorDesc
                      ELSE T1.Color 
                      END AS [text()]
                  FROM Table1 T1
                  WHERE T1.Group = T2.Group
                  ORDER BY T1.Group
                  For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) [Colors]
FROM Table1 T2
```

Comment: Again this one the same as previous displays 'Pink' for GroupId=3, instead of 'The cool name of pink color'

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will provide the answer or it will take you near the answer. Try this since I haven't got time to try in sqlFiddle. Using "Group" as column name is not entertained so please consider another name

```
SELECT DISTINCT Group1,
STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Group1) FROM Table1  WHERE Group1=S.Group1)>1 
             THEN Color 
             ELSE ColorDesc 
        END
        FROM Table1  S
        WHERE T.Group1 = S.Group1
        FOR XML path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') [GroupColor]
FROM Table1  T
```