# T-SQL concatenating multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to concatenate a separate table into my results, but not quite the same way as some of the other questions I've read.
There is a table of classes:

```
ClassID
-------
1
2
3
```

And a Scheduling Table

```
ClassID    Block    Day
-------    -----    ---
1          5        1
1          4        2
1          5        2
2          2        1
2          3        2
3          1        1
3          1        2
3          1        3
```

The Output I'd like is to get all the days grouped by block per class and concat'd into a single line like so:

```
ClassID    Schedule
-------    --------
1          5(1,2) 4(2)
2          1(2) 2(3)
3          1(1,2,3)
```

Is this possible? Another acceptable (possibly easier) output would be

```
ClassID    Schedule
-------    --------
1          5(1) 5(2) 4(2)
2          1(2) 2(3)
3          1(1) 1(2) 1(3)
```

Comment: REFER THIS , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699636/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-one-field/20699732#20699732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate a list of column values with a separator like comma using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.

In this case, you need to do it in a nested manner , once to concatenate the days of a particular `block` and next to concatenate this further based on `class`

Also this is better to do in the GUI layer as performance will be a problem with this kind of manipulation.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dbf0/14)**

```
select classId, stuff(
         (select distinct ' ' + T2.block  + '(' +
         stuff((select  ','+ T1.Day 
         from Table1 T1
         where T1.classId = T2.classId
         and T1.Block = T2.Block
         FOR XML PATH ('')),
               1,1,'') +')'
         from Table1 T2
         where T2.classId = T.classId
         for xml path('')), 1,1,'')

from Table1 T
group by classId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select ClassID
    ,
    stuff
    ((
        select ' ' + t1.Block + '(' +
        stuff
            ((
                select ',' + t2.Day
                from table1 t2
                where t2.ClassID = t.ClassID and t2.Block = t1.Block
                for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') + ')'
        from table1 t1
        where t1.ClassID = t.ClassID
        group by t1.Block
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
from table1 t
group by t.ClassID
```